# What is the Tensorflow 2.4.1 analogous of TPU_strategy.experimental_run_v2 from version 2.1? How to replace that?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tpu

I am following [this old notebook on Kaggle for BERT MLM training](https://www.kaggle.com/riblidezso/finetune-xlm-roberta-on-jigsaw-test-data-with-mlm) where the `tensorflow` version is `2.1`. I cloned and tried running the code but there's an error that `strategy has no experimental_run_v2`.

In the [official documentation of Custom training in TPU's](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training) this piece of information is given but i'm not able to grasp what do I have to change in my code to make it run:

```
# `run` replicates the provided computation and runs it
# with the distributed input.
@tf.function
def distributed_train_step(dataset_inputs):
  per_replica_losses = strategy.run(train_step, args=(dataset_inputs,))
  return strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses,
                         axis=None)

@tf.function
def distributed_test_step(dataset_inputs):
  return strategy.run(test_step, args=(dataset_inputs,))
```

Below is the code which I am trying to run and I have commented the troublesome part. Could someone please help me with proper restructuring of this code?

```
def train_mlm(train_dist_dataset, total_steps=2000, evaluate_every=200):
    step = 0
    ### Training lopp ###
    for tensor in train_dist_dataset:
        distributed_mlm_train_step(tensor) # --------- HERE IS THE ERROR ----- 
        step+=1

        if (step % evaluate_every == 0):   
            ### Print train metrics ###  
            train_metric = train_mlm_loss_metric.result().numpy()
            print("Step %d, train loss: %.2f" % (step, train_metric))     

            ### Reset  metrics ###
            train_mlm_loss_metric.reset_states()
            
        if step  == total_steps:
            break


@tf.function # What Should be replaced with this line of code?
def distributed_mlm_train_step(data):
    strategy.experimental_run_v2(mlm_train_step, args=(data,)) # this is what causing the error
```

I think I have to use something to add the total error like the one in the documentation `strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses, axis=None)` but using this one gave me another obvious error `ValueError: A non-DistributedValues value None cannot be reduced with the given reduce op ReduceOp.SUM.`

Answer (score 0):

[Please see this article with TF 2.6](https://www-tensorflow-org.translate.goog/tutorials/distribute/custom_training?hl=zh-cn&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-GB&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

Things to note in the above example:

- They construct the sum using `for x in ...` iteration. `train_dist_dataset` `test_dist_dataset`
- The scaling loss is distributed_train_step the return value of  `tf.distribute.Strategy.reduce` This value is merged as each replica is used, and then `tf.distribute.Strategy.reduce` spreads across batches by stacking each return value.
- When executed `tf.distribute.Strategy.experimental_run_v2`, it `tf.keras.Metrics` should be updated in `train_step` and `test_step`.

Comment: I don't think it's migration issue as I'm talking about V `2.1` vs `2.4` Is it?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the answer with an example using TF 2.6, hopefully will shed some light